# How to use workspace in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, intellij-14

I am familiar with eclipse. with eclipse I am able to create workspace and I used to work on that. similar to this is there any way to create workspace in intellij?. By default when importing the project the intellij is pointing actual path of the project not asking for workspace to work.

Answer (score 2):

Please [refer to the documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/eclipse.html):

> **No workspace**
>
> The first thing you'll notice when launching IntelliJ IDEA is that it
>   has no workspace concept. This means that you can work with only one
>   project at a time. While in Eclipse you normally have a set of
>   projects that may depend on each other, in IntelliJ IDEA you have a
>   single project that consists of a set of modules.
>
> If you have several unrelated projects, you can open them in separate
>   windows.
>
> If you still want to have several unrelated projects opened in one
>   window, as a workaround you can configure them all in IntelliJ IDEA as
>   modules.